# Trouble with cin function in C++ language

Tags: c++, cin

i wrote a small test code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int a,b,c,d;
    cin>>a>>b,c>>d;
    cout<<a<<" "<<b<<" "<<c<<" "<<d;
    return 0;
}
```

i gave input:

```
1 2 3 4
```

and the output is:

```
1 2 0 0
```

but from my view, it should give some error because of `cin>>a>>b,c`

Why this code is not giving error?

Comment: The comma is an operator, but does something very different to `>>`.  You are wrong in expecting it to give an error, because it is a valid operator.

Comment: You should crank up your compiler warnings. It should tell you about using uninitialized variables, which would help you diagnose what is going on.

Comment: At least, you get points for copying and pasting the actual code, which revealed the typo, instead of just making it up for the question.

Comment: @juanchopanza, actually i used ideone.com, where the compiler shows no warning.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

comma is an operator, >> between integers is shift operator (cin uses overloaded version of this operator).
so your code is equivalent to:

```
cin>>a>>b;
c>>d;
```

both lines are valid, you just ignoring result of second operation

Comment: And the second operation produces undefined behaviour.

Answer (score 3):

According to the [comma operator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_other):

> In a comma expression `E1, E2`, the expression E1 is evaluated, its
>   result is discarded, and its side effects are completed before
>   evaluation of the expression E2 begins (note that a user-defined
>   operator, cannot guarantee sequencing).

So your code `cin>>a>>b,c>>d;` is equivalent to:

```
cin>>a>>b;
c>>d;     // built-in bitwise shift operator. Note c and d isn't initialized yet.
```

which is well-formed.

Answer (score 2):

```
cin>>a>>b,c>>d;
```

should be:

```
cin>>a>>b>>c>>d;
```

it does not gave any error because compilers takes your expression as:

```
cin>>a>>b;
c>>d;  // bit-wise shift operator
```

Answer (score 1):

The comma is a valid operator, it separates expressions that execute one after the other, returning the result of the *left-most* as the value.

So:

```
a = b, c = d;
```

Is equivalent to:

```
a = b;
c = d;
```

So in your case you are doing two separate but valid things:

```
cin >> a >> b, c >> d;
```

Is equivalent to:

```
cin >> a >> b;
c >> d;
```

The `c >> d` is a valid binary shift operation between integers.